# A script to access my shared folder using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I have a script to run a ps1 file using powershell ise on my local machine. `& 'C:\Users\medetrax\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Ward Obs Roaming\Ward Obs Roaming\AppPackages\Ward Obs Roaming_2.4.2.34_AnyCPU_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.ps1'`

However I have now put that ps1 file on my server and wish to access it from powershell using shared folders. What script would I use in powershell for this

```
\\MEDEPADSERVER\Users\Public\app_folder\Ward Obs Roaming_2.4.2.34_AnyCPU_Test
```

I have tried `net use \\MEDEPADSERVER\Users\Public\app_folder\Ward Obs Roaming_2.4.2.34_AnyCPU_Test`
but I get network path errors so does anyone know of any scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mount the share first, then access it using the path:

```
New-PSDrive -Name "Z" PSProvider Filesystem -Root \\MEDEPADSERVER\Users
Test-Path "Z:\Public\app_folder\Ward Obs Roaming_2.4.2.34_AnyCPU_Test"
```

If you get `True` as a response, the drive is mapped correctly and you could execute the script as:

```
&  'Z:\Public\app_folder\Ward Obs Roaming_2.4.2.34_AnyCPU_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.ps1'
```

This assumes that you've set up a share on your server correctly and is named `Users` and is pointing at the correct path on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to execute the script via a UNC path from your local machine.

```
& '\\MEDEPADSERVER\Users\Public\app_folder\Ward Obs Roaming_2.4.2.34_AnyCPU_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.ps1'
```